# Prove that $(12+5i)^n$ for any natural number n isn't a real number.

Tags: complex-numbers, contest-math, recurrence-relations

The solution goes like this:

Let $Y_n = Im((12+5i)^n) = \frac{(12+5i)^n-(12-5i)^n}{2i}$.
Since $12+5i$ and $12-5i$ are the solutions of the following equation: $t^2 = 24t - 169$, then $Y_n$ is the solution to the following recurrence relation: $Y_{n+2} = 24Y_{n+1} - 169Y_n$, for $n = 0, 1, 2, ...$ and $Y_0 = 0$ and $Y_1 = 5$.
Then using simple mathematical induction, we notice that $Y_n$ isn't divisible by $13$ from where it follows that $Y_n$ can't be $0$.

Where I fail to understand the solution is how we acquire the recurrence relation. Does anyone understand it?

Comment: Do you know how to solve second-order linear recursive sequences ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I do, but I don't understand how they got the recursive sequence

Comment: Can you write $(12+5i)^n=r^ne^{in\theta}$ , that is, use the complex polar form for that number? Then you'll immediately see if this is a real number of not.

Comment: Note that the RR should be $ Y_{n+2} = 24 Y_{n+1} - 169 Y_n$. The recurrence follows from the equation. Since those are the roots, hence $(12\pm 5i) ^{n+2} = 24 (12\pm 5i)^{n+1} - 169 ( 12 \pm 5i) ^ n$. We sum up these 2 equations and divide by $2i$.

Comment: @StefanLafon That approach likely requires understanding how to find all rational values of $ \cos ( r \pi )$, where $ r$ is rational. It is arguable if that is easier than the RR solution (also depends on what OP is familiar with).

Comment: @StefanLafon Thank you Stefan but I wanted to understand their solution. Nice approach anyways

Comment: @CalvinLin Thanks a lot Calvin! Now I understand where they got it from

Comment: @MarkoSladojevic The title does not match the body of the question. It is not clear if you 
are looking for a proof vs. just an explanation for the proof you have.